# How can I import a module from another library for an Angular Jest test?

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, spectator

I can successfully run a jest test for a component that uses the `import` command IF I am importing from a relative path or from node_modules.  So, this is working for my.component.spec.ts:

```
import {MyComponent} from './my.component';
import {createComponentFactory, Spectator} from '@ngneat/spectator/jest';
```

In my component template, I want to make use of some shared pipes that are part of another library within the project.  Ideally, it would look like this:

```
import {SharedPipesModule} from '@my-project/shared/pipes';
```

However, this fails with:

> Cannot find module '@my-project/shared/pipes' from ...

I've tried using this in the tsconfig.spec.json, but it did not make a difference.

```
    "paths": {
      "@my-project/shared/pipes": ["libs/shared/pipes/src/index.ts"]
    }
```

I am using Jest v26 and Angular 10.
How can I get the test to successfully import the module I need?

In my package.json, I have:

```
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.0",
    "jest-marbles": "^2.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^8.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.0.0",
```

Comment: Try adding allias to the `tsconfig.json `